# regex where input has & char at end of string

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, regular-language

I am using this regex:

`.*-p(.\d+)-fun\b` meaning:

```
.* => any char at the beginning, 
-p => static string ,
(.\d+) => number in first group,
-fun => static string ,
\b => end of string ,
```

My tests:

```
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun             Matched 
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-funab           not matched
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun&ab=1        Matched
```

Why does the last test match?

It seems & char at the end string seprate them in two string. What is the solution that regex not match in  `http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun&ab=1` ?

`.*-p(.\d+)-fun$` also tested and not working.

Comment: It doesn't match: https://regex101.com/r/H9mzsp/1

Comment: @PawełŁukasik - OP is using .net flavour regex not PCRE

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Look at this  http://regexr.com/3fd4o

Comment: @Moslem7026 you testing example is wrong or use the multiline option to indicate that you are interested in one line at the time: http://regexr.com/3fd4r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex:

```
.*-p(.\d+)-fun$
```

Matches the first example only:

VB.Net code:

```
Dim Tests As New List(Of String)
Dim Pattern As String
Dim Parser As Regex

Tests.Add("http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun")
Tests.Add("http://example.com/abcd-p48343-funab")
Tests.Add("http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun&ab=1")

Pattern = ".*-p(.\d+)-fun\b"
Parser = New Regex(Pattern)
Console.WriteLine("Using pattern: " & Pattern)
For Each Test As String In Tests
    Console.WriteLine(Test & " : " & Parser.IsMatch(Test).ToString)
Next
Console.WriteLine()

Pattern = ".*-p(.\d+)-fun$"
Parser = New Regex(Pattern)
Console.WriteLine("Using pattern: " & Pattern)
For Each Test As String In Tests
    Console.WriteLine(Test & " : " & Parser.IsMatch(Test).ToString)
Next
Console.WriteLine()

Console.ReadKey()
```

Console output:

```
Using pattern: .*-p(.\d+)-fun\b
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun : True
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-funab : False
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun&ab=1 : True

Using pattern: .*-p(.\d+)-fun$
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun : True
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-funab : False
http://example.com/abcd-p48343-fun&ab=1 : False
```